# How to split a String in Robot Framework with delimiter as "|"

Tags: robotframework

I want to split a string using robot framework with delimiter as `|`.

Code:

```
${string} = 'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'
${str}    = Split String    ${string}    '\|'
```

Ouput:

```
Expected: u'Age:2', u'UNACCEPTED'
Actual:   u'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'
```

Could you please assist on same.

Comment: Have you tried ${str}    = Split String    ${string}    | ? (without the '\')

Comment: Yes but it didn't work

Comment: Show what you tried, and the error that you got. We can't read your mind.

Comment: Sure.. I have to verify "Age" in string 'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'. So i want to split string with delimiter as "|".Code i tried:
Code 1:
${string} = 'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'
${str}    = Split String    ${string}    '\|'
Code 2:
${string} = 'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'
${str}    = Split String    ${string}    '|'

But with both codes ${str} returns {u'Age:2|UNACCEPTED'} instead of {u'Age:2',u'UNACCEPTED'}

Comment: You  need to try it like this: ${str} = Split String ${string}    |

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to escape symbols on Robot Framework:

```
${string}=    Set Variable    Age:2|UNACCEPTED
${str}=       String.Split String    ${string}    |
Log       ${str}
Log       ${str}[0]
Log       ${str}[1]
```

Output:

```
['Age:2', 'UNACCEPTED']            # Output of ${str}
Age:2                              # Output of ${str}[0]
UNACCEPTED                         # Output of ${str}[1]
```

---

Unless you want to split a string on an escape character:

```
${string}=    Set Variable    Age:2\nUNACCEPTED\nanother line
${str}=       String.Split String    ${string}    \n
```

Output:

```
INFO : 
${string} = Age:2
UNACCEPTED
another line
INFO : ${str} = [u'Age:2', u'UNACCEPTED', u'another line']
```

Comment: Still not working.. keyword failed with error " no keyword with name 'String.Split String' found"

Comment: Remove `String.` if `Split String` worked without it. Or import String library into the test suite.